# try except not catching on function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am getting this valid error while preprocessing some data:

```
 9:46:56.323 PM default_model Function execution took 6008 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
 9:46:56.322 PM default_model Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 31, in default_model
    train, endog, exog, _, _, rawDf = preprocess(ledger, apps)
  File "/user_code/Wrangling.py", line 73, in preprocess
    raise InsufficientTimespanError(args=(appDf, locDf))
```

That's occurring here:

```
async def default_model(request):
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if not request_json:
        return '{"error": "empty body." }'
    if 'transaction_id' in request_json:
        transaction_id = request_json['transaction_id']

        apps = []  # array of apps whose predictions we want, or uempty for all
        if 'apps' in request_json:
            apps = request_json['apps']

        modelUrl = None
        if 'files' in request_json:
            try:
                files = request_json['files']
                modelUrl = getModelFromFiles(files)
            except:
                return package(transaction_id, error="no model to execute")
        else:
            return package(transaction_id, error="no model to execute")

        if 'ledger' in request_json:
            ledger = request_json['ledger']

            try:
                train, endog, exog, _, _, rawDf = preprocess(ledger, apps)
            # ...
            except InsufficientTimespanError as err:
                return package(transaction_id, error=err.message, appDf=err.args[0], locDf=err.args[1])
```

And preprocess is correctly throwing my custom error:

```
def preprocess(ledger, apps=[]):
    """
    convert ledger from the server, which comes in as an array of csv entries.
    normalize/resample timeseries, returning dataframes
    """
    appDf, locDf = splitLedger(ledger)

    if len(appDf) < 3 or len(locDf) < 3:
        raise InsufficientDataError(args=(appDf, locDf))

    endog = appDf['app_id'].unique().tolist()
    exog = locDf['location_id'].unique().tolist()

    rawDf = normalize(appDf, locDf)
    trainDf = cutoff(rawDf.copy(), apps)
    rawDf = cutoff(rawDf.copy(), apps, trim=False)

    # TODO - uncomment when on realish data
    if len(trainDf) < 2 * WEEKS:
        raise InsufficientTimespanError(args=(appDf, locDf))
```

The thing is, it is in a ``` try``except ``` block precisely because I want to trap the error and return a payload with the error, rather than crashing with a 500 error. But its crashing on my custom error, in the try block, anyway. Right on that line calling `preprocess`.

This must be a failure on my part to conform to proper python code. But I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The environment is python 3.7

Here's where that error is defined, in Wrangling.py:

```
class WranglingError(Exception):
    """Base class for other exceptions"""
    pass


class InsufficientDataError(WranglingError):
    """insufficient data to make a prediction"""

    def __init__(self, message='insufficient data to make a prediction', args=None):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.message = message
        self.args = args


class InsufficientTimespanError(WranglingError):
    """insufficient timespan to make a prediction"""

    def __init__(self, message='insufficient timespan to make a prediction', args=None):
        super().__init__(message)
        self.message = message
        self.args = args
```

And here is how main.py declares (imports) it:

```
from Wrangling import preprocess, InsufficientDataError, InsufficientTimespanError, DataNotNormal, InappropriateValueToPredict
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `InsufficientTimespanError` in `main.py` and `Wrangling.py`.

Comment: adding that now

Comment: I'm stumped....

Comment: What happens if you add another `raise InsufficientTimespanError(...)` statement to the top of `preprocess()`?  Does it catch that one correctly?

Comment: @JohnGordon good idea, thank you for thinking on this with me. I put `raise InsufficientTimespanError(args=(pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame()))` at the top of the method - it still crashes in the same way :(

Comment: Hmm.  What happens if you edit `main.py` to call `preprocess()` normally, without the try/except?

Answer (score 2):

Your `preprocess` function is declared `async`. This means the code in it isn't actually run where you call `preprocess`, but instead when it is eventually `await`ed or passed to a main loop (like `asyncio.run`).  Because the place where it is run is no-longer in the try block in `default_model`, the exception is not caught.

You could fix this in a few ways:

- make `preprocess` not async
- make `default_model` async too, and `await` on `preprocess`.

Comment: I apologize. I had removed "async" from `default_model` method here instead of from `preprocess` -- when posting this I was experimenting with it and copied and pasted that function while it had the async added to it. I do still get the error with an async `default_model` and a synchronous `preprocess`

Answer (score 1):

Do the line numbers in the error match up with the line numbers in your code? If not is it possible that you are seeing the error from a version of the code before you added the try...except?

Comment: yes they do -- at this point I feel pretty sure that this is somehow an effect of google cloud function's environment for python 3.7 .. another thing that I noticed is that I cannot suppress warnings by putting the import in the with block, I must also put all uses of the calls in their own with blocks as well. This is contrary to very many examples of it working differently by only wrapping the import.